# Has anyone successfully displayed Azure Storage Blob hosted Word doc URL in React Native WebView?

Tags: azure, react-native, pdf, webview, ms-word

We have a simple Word Document (Private (no anonymous access)) hosted in Microsoft Azure BlobStorage Private Container with SAS Token enabled and now when we are using React Native Webview the document is unable to display did anyone came across similar issue?

```js
return (
    <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://xyzgazd.blob.core.windows.net/schedules/file-sample_100kB.doc?sv=2018-08-18&sr=b&sig=usjflasjkflajskflafkjamb0AZwnnLhwy3-07-02T12%3A49%3A59Z&sp=r'}}
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
      />
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please URL-encode your SAS token (including `?` in front) and you should be able to see the content. I just tried with a text file in my storage account and it worked when I URL-encoded the SAS token. Without that, I was also getting the same error as you're getting.

Update: The below is the code based on above explanation:

```
var url = "https://xyzgazd.blob.core.windows.net/schedules/file-sample_100kB.doc?sv=2018-08-18&sr=b&sig=usjflasjkflajskflafkjamb0AZwnnLhwy3-07-02T12%3A49%3A59Z&sp=r"

    <WebView
            source={{ uri: 'http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=' + encodedURIComponent(url)}}
            style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
          />
```